# angularjs 1.2.0 $http not send request in $eval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angularjs 1.2.0 $http not send request in $eval

code
http://jsbin.com/oZUFeFI/3/watch?html,js,output

Comment: Please include code in your question, it should be self-contained!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched over to the non-minifed AngularJS and dropped in some breakpoints to see which parts of $http it was hitting and for some reason the sendReq method isn't being called.  Didn't narrow it down entirely but adding a $timeout seems to resolve it:

http://jsbin.com/iZihebI/3/edit

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ng']);

myApp.controller('test', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $scope.get = function(search) {
    console.log(search);
    $timeout(function(){$http.get('http://jsbin.com/')},1);
  };
}).directive('xxx', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var searchScope = scope.$new();
      searchScope.$search = 'search text ...';
      elem.bind('click', function(e) {
        searchScope.$eval(attr.c);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: $timeout should accept a function, not a call to a function. It's possible you are just silencing the error because $timeout is silently failing to execute the *return value* of `$http.get('http://jsbin.com/')`

Comment: @finishingmove well the issue I saw from the OPs post was that the request just wasn't happening, debugging the angular source I saw it wasn't calling sendReq on $http for some reason... adding the $timeout "fixed" it but the thought that it should take a function not the promise that would be returned passed my mind but didn't register 100% I'll try to fix.

Comment: I'm not sure either, saying just in case :)